# PHP strip down text (including html tags)

Tags: php

```
<document page-count="3">

<page number="1">
<table id="p1" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="2">
<table id="p2" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="3">
<table id="p3" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>
```

I'd like that code to echo out every "child" of >>> and <<<. For an example `cat`.
I've been using `str_replace` to minimise every unnecessary text.

I'd like the above to be more like:

```
<row>
    <date>2016-05-30</date>
    <name>name</name>
    <animal>cat</animal>
</row>
```

Reason why I got "(" and ")" is because some "rows" will have multiple values.

I'm looking for a simple way to do this!

Comment: Does any of the answers work or do you need more help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '<document page-count="3">
<page number="1">
<table id="p1" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="2">
<table id="p2" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="3">
<table id="p3" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>';

// if you do not have () around the values use this pattern: /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*(\w+).*(\w+)/ 
// your text seem to indicate that it doesn't have () around the values
preg_match_all("/\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\).*\((\w+)\).*\((\w+)\)/",$str,$match);
// preg_match_all("/\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\).*\((\w+)\).*\((\w+)\)/",strip_tags($str),$match);

var_dump($match);
```

Results in:

```
array(4) {
   [0]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=> string(37) "(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)"
        [1]=> string(37) "(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)"
        [2]=> string(37) "(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)"
      }
   [1]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2016-05-20"
        [1]=> string(10) "2016-05-20"
        [2]=> string(10) "2016-05-20"
      }
   [2]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=> string(4) "name"
        [1]=> string(4) "name"
        [2]=> string(4) "name"
      }
   [3]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=> string(3) "cat"
        [1]=> string(3) "cat"
        [2]=> string(3) "cat"
      }
}
```

But that is regex on HTML and it can cause problems.
If you use strip_tags() it will be safer but on my test string it didn't work well as all the strings bunched up in one line. They should not do that.
I suggest you try with strip_tags first. It probably was a linebreak error on my test string.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/387951bce623573259b81745942c86dd828306db

edit: sorry I forgot how you wanted the result:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06ed1f8075b17af08daf0843f4ba8b1066405da6

```
$str = '<document page-count="3">
<page number="1">
<table id="p1" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>
<page number="2">
<table id="p2" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>
<page number="3">
<table id="p3" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat)<<< </table>
</page>';
preg_match_all("/\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\).*\((\w+)\).*\((\w+)\)/",$str,$match);
//preg_match_all("/\((\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\).*\((\w+)\).*\((\w+)\)/",strip_tags($str),$match);
$newstr= "";
for($i=0;$i<=count($match[0])-1;$i++){
    $newstr .= "<row>
    <date>" . $match[1][$i] ."</date>
    <name>" . $match[2][$i] ."</name>
    <animal>".$match[3][$i] ."</animal>
    </row>
    ";
}
echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
$str = '<document page-count="3">
<page number="1">
<table id="p1" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-20)<<< >>>(name)<<< >>>(cat1)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="2">
<table id="p2" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-21)<<< >>>(name1)<<< >>>(cat2)<<< </table>
</page>

<page number="3">
<table id="p3" data-page="1" data-table="1">>>>(2016-05-22)<<< >>>(name2)<<< >>>(cat3)<<< </table>
</page>';


preg_match_all('/>>>\((.*?)\)<<</', $str, $matches);
$res =  array_chunk($matches[1], 3);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($res);
```

**output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-05-20
            [1] => name
            [2] => cat1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-05-21
            [1] => name1
            [2] => cat2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-05-22
            [1] => name2
            [2] => cat3
        )

)
```

To match your requirement, add below code:-

```
$str = '';
foreach($res as $v){
  $str .= '<row>';
  $str .= "<date>{$v[0]}</date>";
  $str .= "<name>{$v[1]}</name>";
  $str .= "<animal>{$v[2]}</animal>";
  $str .= '</row>';
}
echo $str;
```

**output**:-

```
<row>
<date>2016-05-20</date>
<name>name</name>
<animal>cat1</animal>
</row>
<row>
<date>2016-05-21</date>
<name>name1</name>
<animal>cat2</animal>
</row>
<row>
<date>2016-05-22</date>
<name>name2</name>
<animal>cat3</animal>
</row>
```